# Ruby on Rails installation problems (basic?) Unable to connect to localhost:3000, and ssh key not generated properly for GitHub

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github

I am almost a complete beginner to programming, having studied one book on HTML and CSS, and having watched a foundations of programming course on lynda.com. I have decided to learn Ruby on Rails using the Ruby on Rails Tutorial book (http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book#sec-up_and_running).

As per the instructions in the boook I have navigated to the Engine Yard RoR installer at http://railsinstaller.org/, downloaded the .exe, and have followed their step-by-step installation instructions at http://railsinstaller.org/windows

I have run into a couple of problems. The first time I followed the instructions was a bit of  a mess, as I opened and closed the command line several times, using the windows command line, a BASH command line, and perhaps a third one on separate occasions. Unsurprisingly the process wasn't successful. I then uninstalled all the relevant programs and decided to begin again. The second attempt has been more successful but I've still run into a few problems, and I feel like I need to get them sorted before I proceed any further. I have outlined the narrative of my installation attempt below. I believe that I have a problem with GitHub especially and hope that one of you may be able to point out where I have gone wrong. I have run many Google searches but all of the discussion online is far too advanced for me to follow. I'm sorry to write such a huge amount of text but if you open the link to the step-by-step instructions the narrative should be very easy to follow.

- As per Step 4 in the Engine Yard step-by-step instructions, I entered 'rails s' and then attempted to open 'localhost:3000' in my browser, but the browser couldn't connect to the server. When I followed the instructions the first time I was able to connect, although when I again tried to connect later in the process (during my first run-through) I couldn't. I tried with both Firefox and Chrome. Is not being able to connect here a big problem? Can I ignore it?
- During Step 5 I am asked to 'restart my Command Line Prompt'. Does that mean, to enter 'rails s'?
- In step 8 I am asked to 'edit the welcome index.html which can be found under app/views/welcome/index.html.erb'. However, there is no file path 'app/views/welcome/index.html.erb'. There are 'home/index.html.erb' and posts/index.html.erb, and of those two it is the 'home' path that contains a welcome message, and therefore I assume that it is the correct one to edit? Anyway, I edited it and proceeded. I'm asked to attempt to connect to 'localhost:3000' at this stage, but again the browser wouldn't connect.
- In the same Step 8 I'm asked to 'remove the file at /public/index.html by right clicking on it in Sublime Text'. Firstly, I use Notepad++ and would prefer not to switch, so perhaps somebody could explain how to carry out this action using Notepad++? Am I just to delete that entire file, or simple clear its contents perhaps? Also, there are several 'public' folders in the rails files that I downloaded, but none of them have an 'index' folder within.
- As per Step 9, I set up a GitHub account and created a repository there. Now, I enter 'git init' as per the instructions and am returned:

'chcp' is not recognised as an internal or external conmmand, operable program or batch file.
Initialised empty Git repository in C:/Sites/railsinstaller_demo/.git/
'chcp' is not recognised as an internal or external conmmand, operable program or batch file.

Is the above an error message?

- I then enter 'git add .' as per the instructions in Step 9 and am returned:

'chcp' is not recognised as an internal or external conmmand, operable program or batch file.
'chcp' is not recognised as an internal or external conmmand, operable program or batch file.

Is the above an error?

- I then enter 'git commit -m "first commit"' and to my untrained eyes what I'm returned looks legit.
- I then enter 'git remote add origin git@github.com:accountname/railsinstaller_demo.git' and am returned:

'chcp' is not recognised as an internal or external conmmand, operable program or batch file.
'chcp' is not recognised as an internal or external conmmand, operable program or batch file.

Error?

- I next enter 'publickey' and am returned:

public ssh key has been copied to your clipboard

However, when I got to my GitHub account to enter the key it is not there on my clipboard. Why could that be? I assume this will be a big problem in the future and will prevent me from using GitHub? The Ruby on Rails Tutorial book necessitates that I use GitHub while learning.

- Finally, I enter 'git push origin master' and am returned:

'chcp' is not recognised as an internal or external conmmand, operable program or batch file.
Permission denied (publickey)
fatal:The remote end hung up unexpectedly
'chcp' is not recognised as an internal or external conmmand, operable program or batch file.

I assume that the above is an error message and is due to the ssh key problem that I mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

Well this is gonna be fun.

- If you cannot connect to localhost:3000, your server has not started properly and you will not be able to access your site. Check your console to see what error messages came up when you ran `rails s`.
- Restarting your command prompt would mean closing and reopening your terminal window to reset your shell session.
- If you're being asked to edit files you don't have, you've done something wrong up until this point, eg. missed running some commands. Step 7 had you generate a welcome controller, so that file should indeed exist.
- If you're asked to delete a file, it means to delete the file. Rails doesn't care how. Delete it.
- `chcp` sounds like some random Windows thing that isnt configured properly. I don't use Windows. Can't help you with that one sorry. But if your git is not working correctly, it won't prevent you from learning Rails, but it will prevent you from maintaining revision control, pushing your code to external servers, deploying code, or basically doing anything useful. Suggest googling and fix the problem.